# Check for common element in three lists: it checks for identical lists instead

Tags: python, list

I need to input three lists and make a Boolean check whether there is a common element to all lists. So far it the main part of the code looks like this:

```
def in_all_three(listA, listB, listC):
    for x in listA:
        if x in listB and x in listC:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

I don't know why, but it only returns True if the lists are identical. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: since python is whitespace heavy, could you properly indent your code?

Comment: The moment an element is found which is not common, your code will stop executing. Why? Because, `return` statement is encountered. So, put it at the end, after the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use intersection of [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for this purpose.

```
def check_common_element(listA, listB, listC):
    common_elements = set.intersection(set(listA), set(listB), set(listC))
    if common_elements:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Test case 1: Testing when there is a common value among lists
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = [1,5,6]
list_c = [1,8,9]

print(check_common_element(list_a,list_b,list_c))
# output: True

# Test case 2: Testing when there is no common value among lists
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = [1,5,6]
list_c = [7,8,9]

print(check_common_element(list_a,list_b,list_c))
# output: False
```

As @Reti43 suggested, you can do `return bool(common_elements)` instead of `if-else` as its a better option for the reasons described in the comments below. In that case, the modified function would look like this:

```
def check_common_element(listA, listB, listC):
    common_elements = set.intersection(set(listA), set(listB), set(listC))
    return bool(common_elements)
```

Comment: When checking for membership, sets are the way to go. By the way, the whole if else block can be rewritten as `return bool(common_elements)`.

Comment: The point is the ternary statement reads like `return True if True else False` (assuming the set is not empty), which is a tautology. Besides behind the scenes python will call bool(something) when you put that something in a conditional statement, so returning its boolean value directly is more concise. If someone can handle the idea of `if my_set:`, they can handle `bool(my_set)`. But it's just a heads up.

Comment: @Reti43 agreed. Modified my answer with a reference to your comment as an explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Logically you need to return False only after all items were checked and no match was found. 
In order to do that **you need to RETURN FALSE; after the loop done.**

```
def in_all_three(listA, listB, listC):
for x in listA:
    if x in listB and x in listC:
        return True
return False
```